# Centering div box not working

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, html, margin

I am trying to center a div element in to a container so that the margin is the same throughout my page but my way of centering does not seem to be working. I am using bootstrap and my own custom css page.

Here is the basic html template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
</head>

    <body>
        <div class="nav">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="pull-left">
                    <li>ONE</li>
                    <li>TWO</li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li>LOG IN</li>
                    <li>HELP</li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!--End nav container-->
        </div> <!--End nav-->

        <div class="container">
            <h1>header</h1>
            <p> This is a page about me</p>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

and here is the main.css page I have linked to it:

```
.nav li {
    display: inline; 
    color: #5a5a5a;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container  {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

I've looked at various answers here on stack and online but none seem to work. I also tried using

```
margin-left: auto; 
margin-right: auto;
```

But those did not work for me either.

Comment: simply use a `<center>` html tag

Comment: what div are you trying to center?

Comment: @Mr.coder `center` tag was deprecated in html4 and not supported in html5, very bad advise

Comment: Your centring code works: http://jsfiddle.net/UsebJ/2/, you just aren't aligning the elements within the centred containers

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the width onto the container.

Comment: This answer is I think the best. See working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/57R3p/

Comment: Why is this being upvoted so much? The bootstrap that is being used sets a width of 750px for `.container`

Answer (score -1):

All you need to do is set the `.container` `text-align` property to `text-align: center;`

```
.container  {
    text-align: center;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NfBNc/)

Comment: That also messes up the nav.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl to be fair I have no idea what the OP wants centered... its a poorly worded question